# React Native : Hide header when using nested navigators

Tags: react-native, header, nested, react-navigation

I'm writing a multi-screen app using react navigation and nested navigators. I'm trying to use a tab navigator at the upper level and a stack navigator on the lower one.
Tab navigator let me swipe between screens. Now, in the first screen I put 2 buttons that if pressed navigate to another screen using StackNavigator. The thing is that when I pressed the button both headers are visible. I'd like to hide the upper one, the tab navigator header. Anyone coulde help me?

[image: Layout]

Comment: On your second navigation object, set the header property to null.

Comment: if you want code, post here your navigation code, so i can edit and explain to you.

Comment: Thanks but I noticed header property can be modified only in StackNavigator and not in TabNavigator, as I'd like to do. I solved the issue rendering a Modal instead of a View. However I don't know if it is the best solution but is working for me.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set headerShown option in Tab options to false.
Example code:

```
<Tab.Navigator>
  <Tab.Screen
    name="HomeScreen"
    component={HomeScreen}
    options={{headerShown: false}}
  />
  <Tab.Screen name="ProfileScreen" component={ProfileScreen} />
</Tab.Navigator>
```